# How to generate the shortest possible (alpha)numeric unique ID out of a file path?

Tags: python, uniqueidentifier, sha

I would like to generate numeric or alphanumeric (whichever is easier) unique ID as a function of a file path in `Python`.  I am working on a file parsing application and there is a file entity in the DB with descendants and, in order to have a more compact foreign/primary key than the fully qualified path to a file, I would like to convert it into the shortest possible unique digest as possible.

What are my options to do this?  Can I use `SHA`?

How about if i just took an MD5 checksum out of the fully qualified path string and got something like 1736622845? On a command line, it can be done with

```
echo -n '/my/path/filename' | cksum | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Is that guaranteed to never repeat for two different inputs?  If yes, how would I translate the above `bash` piped command into pure Python so that I don't have to invoke a system call but get the same value?

Comment: You can use `import uuid; uuid.uuid4()` fot that.

Comment: I doubt `UUID` is optimal in terms of size

Comment: You can shorten the `UUID` by taking only the first `N` characters.

Comment: will that compromise uniqueness?

Comment: I think to generate hash from `SHA or MD5` will have too long for you (32 bytes).

Comment: how about if i just took an MD5 checksum out of the fully qualified path string and got something like `1736622845` ?  on a command line, it can be done with `echo -n '/my/path/filename' | cksum`.  is that guaranteed to never repeat for two different inputs?

Comment: Is it ok, but checksum is very expensive and may take long time and hardware.

Comment: not so concerned with speed, it is a backend offline process

Comment: Why do you think that your database's default id will not give you appropriate level of guaratees? It does.

Comment: because it is complicated to insert and retrieve it at the same time.  retrieval is needed for child records

Answer (score 2):

The shortest possible unique ID of a string is the string. 
You can try to use an alphabet that only contains the characters allowed in the path, so that you use less bits (a lot of work, not a lot of benefit, unless your paths really only contain a few characters)

What I think you want is a fairly good short hash function. As soon as you generate a hash function there's a risk of collision. For most hash functions a good rule of thumb is that you have far less entries than the hash value space. There's a theorem to prove that as soon as you have more than `sqrt(key_space)` entries you will (with the best hashes) get collisions half the time.

So if you take say 1000 paths, you should aim at having a hash pace of at least 1.000.000 entries to work with. You can chop up other hash functions (say take only the first 2 bytes of the md5). That should work, but note the increase in collisions (where 2 entries will generate the same value).

Also if you are so keen to save space, store the hash value in binary (large int). It's far shorter than the the usual encodings (base64, or hex) and all the DB functions should work fine.

So say you take md5 and store it as a large int, it will take only 16 bytes to store. But you can also only use 8 or 4 (I wouldn't dare go lower than that).