# Path to bijective unique identifier

Tags: math, hash, md5, sha

I'm trying to name a directory that will contain some cache(image thumbnails). The directory should correspond to a path, for example "C:\Users\username\imageFolder".

What would be a good function `string f(path)` that receives a path and retrieves an unique identifier?
I took into consideration MD5 or SHA functions, but there can be conflicts.
I also took into consideration using UUID, but the function is not bijective(I can't obtain the same output for the same input).

I'm searching for a better answer than this [How to generate the shortest possible (alpha)numeric unique ID out of a file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248532/how-to-generate-the-shortest-possible-alphanumeric-unique-id-out-of-a-file-pat)

Thank you!

Comment: What constraints do you have? Can you not just use the path directly?

Comment: The path itself seems like the perfect key.

Comment: the string has to be the name of a directory, so I can't have the path